# I want to know the status of this patent EP2676544A1

Tags: patentability

EP2676544A1

Trying to find out what the status is of this patent

Comment: Can you please be more specific regarding the information you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The cited document is an application, not a patent. I'm not an expert on European patents, but I checked the status of this application on [Espacenet](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/inpadoc?CC=EP&NR=2676544A1&KC=A1&FT=D&ND=3&date=20131225&DB=&locale=en_EP) and it looks like it has been withdrawn. This is consistent with the status as reported with [Google Patents](https://patents.google.com/patent/EP2676544A1/en?oq=EP2676544A1).

Answer (score 0):

I confirm the previous answer. You can see the whole file history here: https://register.epo.org/application?number=EP12004692&lng=en&tab=doclist

Comment: This is sort of a me too answer. To make it more worthwhile, explain why the EPO is the ultimate resource and perhaps step-by-step instructions. The best answers (of which mine in this case is not) teach as well as provide an answer.

Comment: I thought it would be useful for this asker to go straight from the question to the answer. In addition, the file wrapper gives added value to the answer (which can be useful if you are anticipating something similar). 
The site of the EPO is https://register.epo.org (EPO register in Google will find it), enter the patent number preceded by EP or pn= (or use another field identifier) and select All documents.  Another essential resource is the EPO Publication Server (type this into Google) with its Patenttranslate resource if the document is in a foreign language.

Comment: I agree your answer has value. It just would be better if you would add much if your last comment to it. You can and should edit and improve your answers whenever you want.